# SQL Sever Execution time-out vs .NET SqlCommand.CommandTimeout. Who wins?

Tags: sql-server-2008, timeout, sqlcommand

I tried to find the answer search this page and google with no luck!

If I change the "Execution time-out" on the SQL Server instance (Tools->Options->Query Execution) and sets the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout in the .NET code using the SQL Server. Which property wins?

Cheers
--Jocke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timeout is a connection-level property - it applies to each individual connection.

When you go to 'Tools->Options->Execution timeout' you affect only newly created connection in SQL Server Management Studio - it does not apply to SQL Server Instance you're running queries against.

So SqlCommand.CommandTimeout will certainly 'win'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply AlexS. So even if I create a new connection (after changing the property on the server) the sqlCommand.CommandTimeout will 'override' Execution timeout?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In fact, the setting in SQL Management Studio you're referring to is applied only to connections opened by this instance of SQL Management Studio itself.

Comment: There is nothing to "win". SQL Server engine does not have "command timeout" concept

Answer (score 1):

When you go to "Tools->Options->Execution timeout" in SSMS this sets SqlCommand.CommandTimeout for SSMS. No more, no less.

There is **no** equivalent setting in the SQL Server engine to SqlCommand.CommandTimeout: SQL Server will **not** abort a query for a command timeout because it doesn't issue the command. The client does